# What s the difference between singleton and plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, singleton

I want to know: What is the difference between singleton and plugin?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_extension or https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is their definitions :

JavaScript **[Singleton](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/javascript-singleton-design-pattern/)** pattern ensure that only a single instance of the class may exits in application.

A **plugin** is a piece of software that acts as an add-on to a web browser and gives the browser additional functionality. Plugins can allow a web browser to display additional content it was not originally designed to display.

Answer (score 1):

[Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is a design pattern, allow to initiate a single instance of Class in Application scope

[Plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) is a new feature/extension in an standalone application

Hopes that Helps

Answer (score 1):

### Singleton

A Singleton restricts per definition the creation of multiple instances of one object. That means there exists only one instance which is often called the sharedInstance across the whole application. You will never create a *new* Instance of a Singleton, just call its shareInstance() method which returns or creates and returns the Instance. That supports of course lazy loading and other benefits you can read up [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript).

### Plugin

A Pulgin can be either an extension for an existing application or a design pattern (it's actually called [Extensibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility_pattern)). But both add new functionality to your app.